# Access mongo shell running in docker container in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, shell, docker

I want to create a bash script that removes a user from a mongodb database that is running inside a docker container.

Normally through the terminal I would execute `docker exec -it mycontainername bash`

and then once I'm in the container I execute `mongo mydbname --eval "db.users.remove({"firstname":"Bob"})"`

I just have no idea how to do it in a linux bash script.

After I execute script that contains the `docker exec` command, it leaves the script and opens the docker container's terminal and prompts me to enter a command.

Would using the detached `-d` flag work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out you can replace `bash` with the name of the shell you want to open, so in this case `mongo`.